# Calling @classmethod of abstract super class error -- Python

Tags: python

I am trying to overwrite a classmethod as seen in the code below but am getting the following error

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```
   class A(object):
       @classmethod
       def test(cls, data):
         pass


    class B(A):
       @classmethod
       def test(cls, data):
         pass


    class C(B):
       @classmethod
       def test(cls, data):
         # do something to data
         return super(B, cls).test(data)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to show the call that causes the exception to be raised. The traceback might also be helpful, but at present you aren't showing how the error is caused or by which line of your code.

Comment: @holdenweb Everything that is required to find the error is present. He would only need to create an instance and call the method- there is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comment. Call me pedantic, but the code as shown raises no exceptions. A question is much easier to answer if its code can be pasted and executed.

Comment: `B` is not in the class hierarchy of `C`; why are you using it in the call to `super` in `C.test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super` only works with new-style classes (which in the 2.x series means inheriting from `object`), but `A` is an old-style class.

To fix it, replace `class A():` with `class A(object):`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the code example to represent a less simplified version of my actual code. Your answer needs to be updated to reflect the updated example

Comment: @Jakobovski I don't know what you're trying to do with your code, but given a call such as `super(type, obj)`, `obj` **must** be a subclass or instance of `type`- yours simply disregards that presumption; `B` is not in the hierarchy of `C`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. C now inherits from B

Comment: Thorton. Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

super is an object, not a class. Since test is explicitly a class method, you need to call it using the class of super (in this case "A").

Try replacing the last line with
return A.test(data)

Comment: This will not work because A there are properties in B that are required for A to work

Answer (score 0):

`A` is an old-style class (it does not inherit from `object`), but `super` can *only* be used with new-style classes. Just fix `A`:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls, data):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the code example to represent a less simplified version of my actual code. Your answer needs to be updated to reflect the updated example